# OpenMP #pragma, only one thread working on my code

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, pragma

I am working on a code and I am trying to use more threads according to the guide I have been provided with. It says: "Parallelism is achieved using an OpenMP #pragma to dynamically allocate rows of the image to different threads, with a thread for each processor or core." And here it is in the code:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) // OpenMP

for (int y = 0; y<height; y++){                       // Loop over image rows
    fprintf(stderr, "\rRendering (%d spp) %5.2f%%", samps, 100.*y / (height - 1));
    for (unsigned short x = 0, rng[3] = { 0, 0, y*y*y }; x<width; x++) {  // Loop cols
    ...
```

I tried to change the number of working threads according to this..

I have been looking in the manual, trying to find a solution. I found out that *schedule* is used to define how iterations of the loop are divided among the threads. So "dynamic" is used when the loop iterations are divided into *chunks* whose size is up to me. Since in this line of code the size was set to "1" I tried to change it to a way bigger number but the result doesn't change and still only 1 thread is used.

So I tried to set it to "static" instead but still no improvement.

I tried the "AUTO" option, in such a way that the scheduling session would have been up to the compiler.. still no solution.

I also found out that *private(r)* means that the variable *r* is private to each thread and not shared but that actually doesn't change the final outcome.

The compiler is cl.exe.. I am using Visual Studio 2013.
Any way to increase the number of threads?

Comment: Yeah, how about enabling OpenMP in Visual Studio. Add `/openmp` to the command line or click the switch in the project configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenMP, there are several ways of defining the number of threads to use in a parallel region:

- The main one is the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. To use it, set it in the code's environment prior to running it.
- The function `omp_set_num_threads()`. To use it, call it before reaching a parallel region.
- The `num_threads()` clause of the `parallel` compiler directive.

The relative priority of these is defined by the standard and pretty much boils down to `num_threads()` taking precedence to `omp_set_num_threads()` which takes precedence to `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. If neither of the three is used, then the behaviour is implementation define. This can be for example, launching only one thread, or launching as many threads as there are of 'cores' on the machine, or something else...

That said, are you sure you enabled the OpenMP support at your compiler's level?

Comment: @Tarta, what fixed your problem?